# Trying to write my own string class getting exception in gcc

Tags: c++

Basically what the title says. I have been trying to write my own string class using only char arrays and, while my code works when I run it in Visual Studio, I have trouble with it when using `gcc` .The problem seems to be coming when i try to delete in my `getData` function(can be seen below) The exception I get is:

> Exception thrown at 0x6262436B (ucrtbased.dll) in string.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCBC. occurred
>   My code :

Header:

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#ifndef STRING_STRING_H
#define STRING_STRING_H

#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<fstream>

class String {
private:
    char *data; //holds the text
    size_t maxSize; //maximum number of chars in data
    size_t currentSize; //current number of chars in data

    void getData(const char *, size_t maxSize); //sets currentSize to the other char* size and
                                                // copies the content of the other char* to data
public:
    String(); //default constructor
    ~String(); //destructor

    String(const String &); //copy-constructor(from String)
    String(const char *);   //copy-constructor(from char*)

    String operator=(const String &); //operator= (from string)
    String operator=(const char *);  //operator=(from char*)

    size_t length() const; //currentSize getter

    void addChar(const char); //adds a char to the data array

    void getLine(std::ifstream&,const char); // reads line till deliminator and stores it in this string object(all data previously stored is lost)

    size_t find(const char*); //searches for text in the string and if found returns the starting position , if not found returns -1;

    void print() const; //prints the string object to console

    char* toChar() const; //returns a new allocated char pointer with the text inside (must be deleted afterwards)
};


#endif //STRING_STRING_H
```

cpp:

```
#include "String.h"


String::String() {
    currentSize = 0;
    maxSize = 16;
    try {
        data = new char[maxSize];
        data[0] = '\0';
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc &) {
        std::cerr << "Not enough memory" << std::endl;
        throw;
    }
}

String::~String() {
    delete[] data;
}

size_t String::length() const {
    return currentSize;
}

String::String(const String &other) {
    this->maxSize = other.maxSize;
    getData(other.data, maxSize);
}

String::String(const char *other) {
    this->maxSize = strlen(other) *2;
    getData(other, maxSize);
}

void String::getData(const char *dataSource, size_t maxSize) {
    currentSize = strlen(dataSource);
    try {
        char *newData = new char[maxSize];
        delete[] data;
        data = newData;
        strcpy(data, dataSource);
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc &) {
        std::cerr << "Not enough memory" << std::endl;
        throw;
    }
}


String String::operator=(const String &other) {
    if (this != &other) {
        maxSize = other.maxSize;
        getData(other.data, maxSize);
    }
    return *this;
}

String String::operator=(const char *other) {
    if (this->data != other) {
        maxSize = strlen(other) *2;
        getData(other, maxSize);
    }
    return *this;
}

void String::addChar(const char newChar) {
    if (maxSize == currentSize+1) {
        maxSize *= 2;
        getData(this->data, maxSize);
    }
    data[currentSize++] = newChar;
}

void String::getLine(std::ifstream & is, const char delim='\n')
{
    char temp;
    while (!is.eof())
    {
        is.get(temp);
        if (temp == delim)
            break;
        else
            addChar(temp);
    }
    return;
}

size_t String::find(const char * text)
{
    size_t currPos=-1;
    bool found = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < currentSize; i++)
    {
        if (data[i] == text[0])
        {
            for (size_t j = i+1; j < currentSize; j++)
            {
                if (data[j] == text[j - i])
                    found = 1;
                else
                {
                    found = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (found == 1)
            {
                currPos = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return currPos;
}

void String::print() const
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < currentSize; i++)
    {
        std::cout << data[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

char * String::toChar() const
{
    char* text= new char[currentSize+1];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < currentSize; i++)
    {
        text[i] = data[i];
    }
    text[currentSize + 1] = 0;
    return text;
}
```

Comment: If you're using `gcc` try adding the `-ggdb3` flag for debugging that'll point you to specific lines of code that are failing. Much easier to deal with than hex addresses.

Comment: A couple of minor comments on the design. `getData` looks more like it should be called `setData`. `String(const char*)` is not a copy constructor; a copy constructor copies an object of the same type. And in the `String` constructor, either handle the error locally or throw exceptions; don't partially process the error by writing out an error message then rethrowing the exception.

Comment: I feel like catching `bad_alloc` just to print and rethrow is a bad idea. It's possible the print will throw instead. Even if it doesn't, your class' user is likely not expecting your class to print things in his terminal. The fact that an exception was thrown should be evident enough.

Comment: When you do `getData(this->data, maxSize)` then `data` and `dataSource` point to the same thing. Then, you `delete[] data;` and read from `dataSource` in `strcpy(data, dataSource);`. Since you deleted `data` and `dataSource` point to the same thing, you are reading a deleted object.

Comment: Your `getData` method allocates buffer of `maxSize` regardless of the size  of the string being copied. If it is longer than `maxSize` you'll have buffer overrun.

Comment: @VTT No, `maxSize` in `getData` refers to the function's argument and not the member `maxSize` (although someimtes `getData` is called with member `maxSize`).

Comment: [mcve], post it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes, however buffer overrun is still possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is caused by calling `delete []` on uninitialized memory.

In the copy constructor, the `data` member is not initialized before calling `getData()`. In `getData()`, you are using `delete [] data;`.

You could initialize `data` to `nullptr` in the constructors to avoid the problem.

It's always a good idea to initialize all variables to some sensible value before the body of the constructor. E.g. you can implement the copy constructor as:

```
String::String(const String &other) : currentSize(0),
                                      maxSize(other.maxSize),
                                      data(nullptr)
{
    getData(other.data, maxSize);
}
```

Similarly, implement the constructor from `char const*`   as:

```
String::String(const char *other) : currentSize(0),
                                    maxSize(strlen(other) *2),
                                    data(nullptr)
{
    getData(other, maxSize);
}
```

Comment: That seems to have solved it and is something I should definitely pick up as a good practice .Thank you!